# How to retrive/view saved passwords from the Android browser

Tags: android, google-chrome

How to retrive/view saved passwords from the Android browser?

one more question:- How to auto save password without notification/prompting in any Android or Google chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

(1)   If you have androidSDK tools installed (adb) you can do this on windows.

**Code ::**

adb shell

sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db

.table

select * from password;

(2)   If you use firefox browser you can autosave password with the follwing steps ::

i) First you need to close firefox.

ii) Now locate the nsloginmanagerprompter.js which is normally found in

C:\ProgramFiles\MozillaFirefox\Components\

iii) Open nsloginmanagerprompter.js with notepad

iv) Replace the entire line 804 to 869 with the following code

var pwmgr = this._pwmgr;

pwmgr.addLogin(aLogin);

When you've done that "save as" to your desktop, then drag back in to
the original folder and replace the file.

Now your done go into firefox and try it out..

Or You can try with "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastpass.lpandroid&hl=en"

Comment: Thanks Asishint.How to autosave in chrome without notification?

Comment: For chrome you can use "autocomplete=on" extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-%3D-on/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh